# Virtual Box not responding after guided installation

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I've followed the assisted installation for installing Debian (version 11.3.0) on a virtual machine with the latest version of Virtual Box (version 7.0).
It's the first time I follow the guided or assisted installation, and last time I installed Debian on a virtual machine was this summer, and all worked fine.

This is [the state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oBIc.jpg) of my virtual machine when I switch it on.

It doesn't respond either to the keyboard or the mouse.
Does someone know from where the issue may arise or what should I do to get my machine working?

The installation took at least 30 minutes, contrarily to the manual installation I was used to that takes about 10-15 minutes.

I tried both the graphical installing and the installing on the command line, and installed LXDE.

Thank you a lot,

Fab

Comment: Can you try a different machine?  Get a Debian ISO, make a new machine, give it ample disk (75 to 100 GB) and 3 GB of memory. Set it to install from the ISO and install it yourself.  See if that works. This is how I install a VM.

Comment: Are you able to get into the boot options ?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestions. What I did was getting back from version 7.1 of VirtualBox to version 6.1, and it worked. I wonder whether I had a version of VB compatible with Windows